# Put series title tags in one group?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I sometimes look for general tags like [resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise) and [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) on the Tags page of the main site and am overwhelmed by the series title tags that populate the pages. I suspect that if we separate the series title tags from the general tags, the general tags would only occupy no more than three pages. I propose on the grounds of user friendliness and usability that there be new tabs named *all*, *general* and *series* in addition to and replacing some of the currently existing *popular*, *name* and *new* tabs on the Tags page of the main site.

Comment: This involves a big change in the way the tag is stored, so I doubt it will get implemented any time soon.

Comment: There are a very small number of non-series tags on this site, and very few are created on an ongoing basis. If you think it would be helpful, we could always maintain a meta post with information about non-series tags (I was working on this at one point, but stopped for some reason that I no longer remember). nhahtdh is right in that there's plain no way this is going to get implemented as a baked-in feature of the tagging system.

Comment: @senshin That is the way to go. I think this will benefit new users the most.