# List of non-series tags on the main site

Tags: discussion, tags

[Gao Weiwei was looking for a list of non-series tags on the main site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1196/1908), and it so happens that I found the list of them I had been keeping a while back. So here we go.

Answer (score 3):

[**Here is a Data Explorer query that contains some information about non-series tags.**](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/261964)

As new non-series tags are created, I will update this query. We don't get new non-series tags very often, though, so this will be infrequent. (It would be possible to do this without a hardcoded list if we were to include some sort of annotation in tag wikis to indicate which tags are non-series, but that seems like it might be overkill.)

If you notice a non-series tag I've missed, leave a comment here and I'll update. Also, if you have better suggestions for the categorization scheme (`TagType`), I'm all ears.

Rather than updating this post whenever we have new series tags, I will just update the query. When you click through to the query, there is a blurb that will say something like "edited feb 5"; that will tell you the last time I updated the query.